# How to access instance variable from another class in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

I am trying to implement a tree data structure.   currently I am having an issue programming the addNode() method in GeneralTree.java. I want to do a check to see if the GeneralTree.root() is null, and if so add data to the node. I am having issues accessing the data instance variable from the GeneralNode class in the GeneralTree class.

GeneralNode.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class GeneralNode {
    int data;
    GeneralNode parent;
    ArrayList<GeneralNode> children;

    public void setData(int i){
        data = i;
    }

    public int getData(){
        return data;

    }
    }
```

GeneralTree.Java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class GeneralTree {

    GeneralNode root;


public GeneralTree(){

}

public void addNode(int data){
    if (GeneralTree.root == null){
        root.setData(data);
    }


}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    return root == null;
}

public GeneralNode root(){
    return root;
}

/*
public int getPosition(){
    return position;
}
*/
public static void main(String[] args){
    GeneralTree myTree = new GeneralTree();
    System.out.println(myTree);
    System.out.println(myTree.root());
    System.out.println(myTree.isEmpty());



}

}
```

Comment: Static variables in java are always accessed by `ClassName.classVariable`. Make sure even in assignments, you are referencing it in that way.

Comment: Can you specify what "I am having issues" means? Do you get a compile error, an Exception while running it? Currently you're question is quite unclear.

Comment: If you want `root` to be non-null, you should probably do `root = new GeneralNode()`. After that you can also do `root.setData(data);` as in your existing code, but I’m not sure you want it inside the `if` statement?

Comment: You are correct in your code when you only access the variable through the getter and in this case the setter.

Comment: Another option you should give a thought: `root = GeneralNode(data);`. It requires that your `GeneralNode` class has a constructor that accepts `data` as argument (you may want it to accept other arguments along with `data`).

Answer (score 0):

Your addNode method should not compile because root is not static, so you should access it directly, class name is not needed. 
And the condition should be != null:

```
public void addNode(int data){
    if (root != null){ //updated line
        root.setData(data);
    }
}
```

Also, your constructor should initialize root:

```
public GeneralTree() {
    root = new GeneralNode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant reach the `root` reference like `GeneralTree.root` if reference is not static. If root's value is same for all GeneralTree object, you declare it as static.

If root's value is not same for all GeneralTree object, change your method like this:

```
public void addNode(int data){
if (this.root == null){
    root.setData(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you need to either create an instance of the GeneralNode or to make the class static.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    GeneralTree myTree = new GeneralTree();

    GeneralNode theGeneralNode = new GeneralNode();

    System.out.println(myTree);
    System.out.println(myTree.root());
    System.out.println(myTree.isEmpty());

}
```

afterwards you can theGeneralNode to reference data in it.